# Amazon cdk pipeline deploy returns KMS 400

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am following steps from the document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/codepipeline_example.html to deploy a simple `lambda` function using cdk. On running the `cdk deploy PipelineDeployingLambdaStack` command, the cloud formation creation begins but fails at  `AWS::KMS::Key| Pipeline/ArtifactsBucketEncryptionKey`. How can I fix this? what am I missing?

Comment: What is the error message in Cloudformation?

Comment: One of the target environments has not been bootstrapped with the new bootstrap stack. Make sure all your target environments are bootstrapped. Refer : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cdk_pipeline.html and see if it helps